# Retrofit callbacks and saveinstanceState

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a doubt regarding Retrofit2 callback and onSaveInstanceState. I want to save the state of two variables, **var1** and **var2** in **onSaveInstanceState**. The two variables(actually are not simple variables) take their values in the **Retrofit callback in onResponse method**.It lasts only  milliseconds but if i rotate the device before the two variables get their values in onResponse the app crash.  I don't know very well how to tackle this situation. I would like to know your approaches regarding this to avoid the crash.(Actually i have 2 retrofit callbacks, they are independent from each other, one for drawing a graphic and the other one for presenting data in textviews). Thanks in advance and excuse for my poor english language skills.

```
  @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("var1",var1);
        outState.putInt("var2",var2);

   }

  retrofitcallback() {
       return new Callback<T>() {
                    public void onResponse() {
                       var1=...
                       var2=...
                    }
                    public void onFailure() {
                    }
       };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, the app may crashes because var1 and var2 are nulls.

And more important - I suggest you to think about your client-server design. You're using callbacks and retrofit calls in UI classes - it's bad approach, since it leads to memory leaks and it's hardly possible to manage lifecycle. Consider to use loaders or services, it would be much better and also easier for you.

P.S. When you app crashes, always provide the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't use loaders since i'm not using a database.  By services i suppose that you mean IntentService, i have thought it before, but i don't understand very well the benefits of using a service, i still need to save the result of the service in a variable and use it in onSaveInstanceState and if the user rotates the screen before the service finishes i would have the same problem, wouldn't i?

Comment: You can use loaders without database also. Loaders with LoaderManager takes care about Activity/Fragment lifecycle. You just send request in loader onForceLoad method and in the retrofit callback call deliverResult. All your data won't be destroyed when activity is restarting. 
The same thing you can achieve with Service (usual Service or IntentService - doesn't matter), but it'll be harder to retrieve result. Otto/EventBus as a possible variants.